# Extracting value from a string field with regex in grafana

Tags: json, elasticsearch, lucene, grafana

I am creating grafana dashboard on the elastic search logs available for my mule application to 
    check the error details in any api . The issue I am facing is all the payload with error details are 
    being populated in the message element as a string . Can any one help me with any way to extract the 
    error code and error message from this log and show in grafana ?
    Here's my document in elastic search : I want to extract Error code: BAD Request with some regex

```
{
   "_index": "local.logevent.balance-v1",
   "_type": "_doc",
   "_id": "kymRP20Bp8CiWs3OefJO",
   "_version": 1,
   "_score": null,
   "_source": {
   "timeMillis": 1568729560968,
   "thread": "[balance-api-09].httpListenerConfig.worker.01",
   "level": "ERROR",
   "loggerName": "org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor",
   "message": "Transaction [null] - Error Code [BAD_REQUEST] - Error Message [] - Error Description 
   []",
   "endOfBatch": false,
   "loggerFqcn": "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLocationAwareLog",
   "contextMap": {},
   "threadId": 20,
   "threadPriority": 5
   },
   "fields": {
   "timeMillis": [
    "2019-09-17T14:12:40.968Z"
   ]
  },
  "highlight": {
   "level": [
     "@kibana-highlighted-field@ERROR@/kibana-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1568729560968
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you use Logstash?

Comment: yea. the snippet given is what I get in Kibana.The issue is everything under the message field is considered as string

Answer (score 0):

- GoTo: Management section in kibana
- Select you index (local.logevent.balance-v1)
- Search for message field, check if this field is aggregatable
- If it is not aggregatable you can change the type of this field to keyword via template
- If the above is not possible, then try to parse message field in logstash and create a seperate field for Error Code and Error Message.